# Does ArcGIS support curves in geopackage?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geopackage, true-curves

When I export a featureclass to a geopackage (with spatial type 'geopackage') in ArcGIS 10.4, true curves are densified to lines consisting of many short straight segments.

Is this a shortcoming of the export method, or of the capabilities of geopackage? I couldn't find anything about support of curves by geopackage.

Comment: If you read http://www.geopackage.org/spec/ you should find that the core standard supports only linear geometry types but the "GeoPackage Non-Linear Geometry Types" extension adds support for CircularString, CompoundCurve, CurvePolygon, MultiCurve, MultiSurface, Curve, and Surface. I do not know what is the level of support in ArcGIS 10.4.

Comment: Gdal 2.x, ogr2ogr seems to write Curves to a Geopackage, so it seems Geopackage supports curves.
https://gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html